# How to write a big ISO file into a few disks for using its content?

Tags: iso-image

I have a big ISO file (7G) and I need to convert it to actual content (it is a set of installation disks). I used ImgBurn in the past to write an ISO file to a single DVD, but ImgBurn seems to be unable to handle my current situation. Am I wrong? What other tools can I use?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using a DVD-DL media or any software may fail to burn the ISO. The DL media can hold about twice as much data as a standard DVD-R, which should be enough for your 7GB file.

I've been using [ISO Recorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm) to burn for quite some time without issues.  Once installed, just right click your ISO file and choose 'copy image to CD/DVD'.

Comment: Thanks soooo much for helping me! Unfortunately I dont have DVD-DL. Regards.

Comment: @curious1 This is the only option if you want to make sure the ISO works afterwards. Technically it would be possible to use 7-zip or winrar to extract the contents of the ISO and have all the files, then zip it to several archives, and burn those archives, but from that moment on, if there are checks on the media for that iso, it will no longer install.

Comment: Melikoth and LPChip, thanks for chiming in. I did further research and realized that all you said is TRUE!!!